# How to use dblink with nopassword in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am new to postgreSQL and I am trying pull data from a remote server using the dblink module.

For example:

```
dblink('host=remoteserver port=5432 dbname=test password=123456','select* from table1') t1(.....);
```

Using this method the password is visible to anybody. I would prefer to get the password from a pgpass file.

Is it possible to get a password from a pgpass file and use it in dblink?

Comment: I don't understand the logic in that. No matter what you will do you will need to provide password for connection. Wether it will be visiable or by variable, or by read from file.

Comment: if we use $psql -h remotehost -d test -U postgres -w ---here -w option will fetch the password from pgpass file ..like that i need to get it for dblink